# Getting the class instance through a property

Tags: c#, class, reference

Assume for example that I have created the following class and make an instance on the run (Trigged by a mouseclick event);

```
Public class myObject{
    public String name {get;set;}
    public Int64 id {get;set;}
    public String randomProperty {get;set;}

    public myObject(){
        this.name = "";
        this.id = 0;
        this.randomProperty = "";
    }
}
```

If I have only got the name property, how can I access the rest of the class properties. (So I have got only the String property of the instance.)

I can imagine the steps will be as follows:

String --> check the parent instance class --> get the reference of the class --> access to other properties in that class.

Is this possible at all or not, and if so how can I accomplish it?

@Edit - because it is unclear to people (Used a simplified example to keep it simple..)

Say I have got a popup class which contains amongst other things a border.
Through the children of the window I can access the correct border property.
My question; how can I get from the border to the instance of the Popup class and through the instance to the other properties:

Border --> instance of the popup --> other properties

Comment: Show an example. It's totally unclear what you mean by "If I have only got the name property".

Comment: So you have a string variable and you want to know what myObject instance refers to that particular string?

Comment: @usr Yes that is exactly what i want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a string variable and you want to know what `myObject` instance refers to that particular string.

That is not possible because the string does not store information about incoming references. Objects are not "owned" in .NET.

You'll have to track that information yourself. For example instead of passing a string to some piece of code pass the `myObject` instance it came from. Or a `Tuple<MyObject, string>` to pass both objects.